# String parameter to MVC4 Controller using jQuery Tabs

Tags: jquery, c#-4.0, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC4 razor view (index.cshtml) with the following jQuery generated tab links:

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
       <li><a href="/MetaData/Edit?Name=@item.Name">@item.DisplayName</a></li>
    }
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1">

</div>
</div>
```

Generated via the following controller method:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return PartialView("Index", db.MetaDatas.ToList());
    }
```

Secondly, the related controller method for each tab link is as follows:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Edit(string Name = "")
    {
        MetaData item = db.MetaDatas.Where(md => md.Name.Equals(Name)).Single();

        if (item == null)
        {
            return PartialView(null);
        }
        return PartialView(item);
    }
```

Which loads edit.cshtml via ajax into the tabs div as follows:

```
@model Data.MetaData
<div id="_metadata_content">

    <div class="message-success">@ViewBag.SuccessMessage</div>
    <div class="message-error">@ViewBag.ErrorMessage</div>

    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Edit", "MetaData", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "_metadata_content", HttpMethod = "POST" }
    ))
    {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>MetaData</legend>

        <h2>@Model.DisplayName</h2>

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Name)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.DisplayName)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AllowEdit)

        <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Val, new { @cols = 80, @rows = 10 })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Val)
        </div>
        <p>
        @if(Model.AllowEdit)
        {
            <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
        }
        </p>
    </fieldset>

    }
</div>
```

The form save button links to the following controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(MetaData metaData)
{
    ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "Error updating value";
    ViewBag.SuccessMessage = "";
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
    db.Entry(metaData).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
    ViewBag.SuccessMessage = "Value updated successfully";
    ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "";
    }

    return PartialView("Edit", metaData);
}
```

The saving works correctly and successfully calls the controller Edit method.  On return the SuccessMessage and ErrorMessage values are updated correctly.

However, if another tab is selected the @ViewBag.SuccessMessage and @ViewBag.ErrorMessage values are not propogated through to edit.cshtml.  Although the values are saved correctly to the database.

I have a feeling this has to do with the construction of the jQuery tab link /MetaData/Edit?Name=@item.Name.  Reason being I have an identically structured page in another part of the system however I construct the link using /Controller/Action/@Model.Value.  For some reason I cannot structure the link like this with a string parameter, it simply comes through as null, hence I have used ?Name=@item.Name.

Any one got any ideas or experienced a similar issue before?